# substrings find and replace in large string using java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have list of articles in html.In every article i have multiple image tags like added below

```
<img alt="quick-start" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-16745" height="224" sizes="(max-width: 474px) 100vw, 474px" src="http://localhost/myfolder/my-content/uploads/2016/11/Quick-start.jpg" srcset="http://localhost/myfolder/my-content/uploads/2016/11/Quick-start.jpg 474w, http://localhost/myfolder/my-content/uploads/2016/11/Quick-start-300x142.jpg 300w" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" width="474" />
```

Problem Statement:
I want to replace urls of image present in **src, srcset** i-e http://localhost/myfolder/my-content/uploads/2016/11/Quick-start.jpg   to some other url.
whats the best approach to do that.  I am thinking about functional programming in java

Comment: Your problem description is a bit unclear and I don't see how functional programming can help here in an efficient way. Maybe you should look at regular expressions instead. Read about [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Or maybe something like `String.replace("http://abc", "http://xyz")` is sufficient already.

Comment: It can be done with almost any language that is able to process textfiles. Java is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using java.But it will be easy if you manipulate using java script framework like jquery.

```
$(".image2").attr("src","image1.jpg");
```